# MySQL - log every connections

Tags: mysql, logging, connection

I'd like to monitor a MySQL 5.0.77 server and log every incoming connection for a day.
I need to know who is connecting to the database.

I tried with the general logging but it's logging **way too much** and I can't keep it on long enough, log file is growing too fast.

Is there a way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: See this related bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28377

Comment: you need to know only from where or from where and on what database ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use general log, not as a text file, but as a MySQL table.

## Why create the general_log as a table?

- You can run SQL against it.
- You can rotate out very easily.

## How do you configure it?

Starting in MySQL 5.1, the following option was introduced: [**log-output**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output).

- Setting `log-output` to `FILE` (default) writes log entries to the text file.
- Setting `log-output` to `TABLE` writes log entries to `mysql.general_log`.
- Setting `log-output` to `TABLE,FILE` writes log entries to `mysql.general_log` and the text file.

There is one major thing that must be changed.

Let's look at a standard mysql.general_log table:

```
mysql> show create table mysql.general_log\G 
*************************** 1. row *************************** 
       Table: general_log 
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` ( 
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL, 
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log' 
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

It's a CSV file ? Yuck !!! Who has time for that? Not to worry, turn it into a MyISAM table

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ENGINE = MyISAM; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ADD INDEX (event_time);
```

If you already started MySQL, do it like this instead:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ENGINE = MyISAM; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ADD INDEX (event_time); 
SET GLOBAL general_log = @old_log_state;
```

Now, the general log table looks like this:

```
mysql> show create table general_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: general_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `event_time` (`event_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## How do you rotate the general log when it's a MyISAM table?

Here is an example of how to blank out `mysql.general_log`:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; 
CREATE TABLE mysql.general_log_new LIKE mysql.general_log; 
DROP TABLE mysql.general_log; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log_new RENAME mysql.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = @old_log_state;
```

Here is an example of how to keep the last 3 days of entries:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; 
CREATE TABLE mysql.general_log_new LIKE mysql.general_log; 
INSERT INTO mysql.general_log_new 
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log WHERE event_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY; 
DROP TABLE mysql.general_log; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log_new RENAME mysql.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = @old_log_state;
```

## CAVEAT

This feature is available in MySQL 5.1/5,5/5.6. You should upgrade from MySQL 5.0.77 to the latest

## EPILOGUE

I could write a lot more here but have discussed this many times in the DBA StackExchange. here are some of my posts on this subject:

- `Feb 11, 2012` : [**`MySQL general log`**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log/12672#12672)
- `Jan 07, 2012` : [**`How to enable MySQL general log?`**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log/10346#10346)
- `Dec 27, 2011` : [**`How to do MySQL User Accounting`**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/how-to-do-mysql-user-accounting/9776#9776)
- `Feb 24, 2011` : [**`Audit logins on MySQL database`**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database/1434#1434)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, but it might not work.
Create a FIFO pipe in `/var/log/mysql/named_pipe`
In one end, get MySQL to use it as the general log file filename.

On the other end, set up something like

```
grep "login" < /var/log/mysql/named_pipe > /var/log/mysql/logins
```

You'll need to grep for whatever line it is exactly that you're after out of the log.

It *might* work.. it might not.

Comment: Even if this does work, there is a performance hit for all this logging.

Comment: you want the data or not?  You're gonna have to log it at *some* level.  Other options might include mysql proxy, but you've still gotta write it to disk at *some point*

Comment: mysql refuses to start when the log file is a FIFO pipe. I don't want to data, only the "Connect" information. I'm not worried about the performance hit if it's only for a day.

Comment: tcpdump or ngrep.. then scrape the information out of the packets.  MySQL sucks.  Especially when it's picky about it's log files.

Comment: Well sure, you need to log it, but using the general log is overkill.

Comment: If there's a way to redirect a specific data from the general log 'Connect' and truncate the log file, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing.  In MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7, there is a way to capture the information needed and store it in a table.  I'm not sure if this is possible with MySQL 5.0 or 5.5.  Here is what I did:

1. Created a database to contain the tables needed.
2. Created the tables needed
3. Created a procedure to capture the information and insert into the tables
4. Modified the MySQL configuration file so all connections execute the stored procedure
5. Gave all users execute privilege on the stored procedure.

Note:  This will not capture information if a user connects with super or root like privileges.

In the mysqld section of the MySQL configuration file, I added:
`# ***` Parameter below logs user connections

```
init_connect='CALL connectionlogging.usp_InsertUserConnection'
```

Information I need to capture is userid, host the connection request is coming from, the database the user is connecting to, information about the connection, and a timestamp.

I use this information to determine who is using an encrypted connection, what database(s) they are connecting to, and when the user connects.